# Asymptotic distribution of t-test with two coefficients

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, t-test, asymptotics

I have the following CEF:

$$
y_{i}=\beta_{1} d_{i}+\beta_{2}\left(1-d_{i}\right)+e_{i}
$$

And the following assumptions:

$$
d_{i} \perp\left(y_{i}(0), y_{i}(1)\right)
$$

$$
\mathrm{E}\left[e_{i} \mid d_{i}\right]=0
$$

I would like to get the asymptotic distribution of the following t-test: $$
\mathrm{H}_{0}: \beta_{1}-\beta_{2}=0 \text { v.s. } \mathrm{H}_{1}: \beta_{1}-\beta_{2} \neq 0
$$

$$
t_{n}=\frac{\widehat{\beta}_{1}-\widehat{\beta}_{2}}{\text { s.e. }\left(\widehat{\beta}_{1}-\widehat{\beta}_{2}\right)}
$$

Nevertheless, I do not know how to obtain the asymptotic distribution with two variables. One variable would be like:

Under $H_{0}: \beta_{1} \stackrel{}{=} \mathrm{}0$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
t_{n} &=\frac{\widehat{\beta}_{1}}{\text { s.e. }\left[\widehat{\beta}_{1}\right]} \\
& \stackrel{\beta_{1}=0}{=} \sqrt{n} \frac{\widehat{\beta}_{1}-\beta_{1}}{\sqrt{\left[n \widehat{V}_{1}(\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}})\right]_{22}}} \\
&=\left(\sqrt{\left[n \widehat{V}_{1}(\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}})\right]_{22}}\right)^{-1}(01) \sqrt{n}(\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}-\boldsymbol{\beta}) \\
& \stackrel{\text { CMT,CWD,Slutsky }}{\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}}\left(\sqrt{[V(\boldsymbol{\beta})]_{22}}\right)^{-1} N\left(0,[V(\boldsymbol{\beta})]_{22}\right) \\
&=N(0,1),
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: You can't obtain any result until you supply some assumptions!  This notation usually appears in an ordinary least squares regression context.  When the assumptions are *iid* zero-mean common-variance Normal errors, you don't even need asymptotics: the difference of estimates has a Normal distribution and the $t$ statistic *exactly* follows a Student $t$ distribution.  Please, then, tell us the context of your work, what assumptions you are making, and what you are varying as you make $n$ (whatever that might represent) grow large.

Comment: @whuber, thanks for the comments. I have just updated my question, taking them into account.

Comment: What is a "CEF"?  What kinds of objects are your symbols referring to (it's difficult to determine what are data, what are random variables, what are parameters, or what are constants)?  If you make no assumptions about the errors other than zero-mean, then you cannot succeed in any asymptotic analysis.  And, again, *what changes* as $n$ increases?  What is $n$?

Comment: Conditional Expectation Function (CEF) is a very common function used in Econometrics. N is the number of observations. We are trying to analyze the results of regression (CEF) by doing a hypothesis test.

Comment: One would guess $n$ is the number.  But *what changes as the observations increase?* For instance, if you are running an experiment then you decide what values to set one or more explanatory variables to.  How do you set them as $n$ increases?  *The asymptotics depend on this.*  If instead your explanatory variables are observed and you model them as random variables, then *what distribution do you suppose them to have?*  The asymptotics depends on that.

Comment: Finally, there's nothing so far to distinguish your question from one you already seem to know the answer to: simply by rewriting your model as $y_i = (\beta_1-\beta_2)d_i + \beta_2 + e_i$ you are in a standard regression setting and you are testing whether the coefficient of $d_i$ is nonzero.